# jQuery mouseover / mouseout show/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, mouseout

The blue square, shown in the picture, is `buttonShowHidePicture` (a button) and the red square is  `currentPictures` (a `div`).

[image]

**Desired functionality**: when I move the mouse over the button I want the div to appear, then I want to be able to move the mouse over the div and click on one of the pictures. When the cursors it's out of the div the div must disappear.

**Issue I'm facing**: however, the code below works as long as I don't scroll down: when I move the cursor on the pictures on the bottom the div scrolls back up because it triggers the hide/show all the time. How can I fix this?

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#buttonShowHidePicture, #currentPictures').mouseover(function () {
    $('#currentPictures').show();
});

$('#currentPictures, #buttonShowHidePicture').mouseout(function () {
    $('#currentPictures').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mouseleave event instead of mouseout. Because hide event is also firing on your images which is inside a div.

```
$('#currentPictures, #buttonShowHidePicture').mouseleave(function () {
$('#currentPictures').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the behave!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').mouseover(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('>.actions', this).css('visibility', 'visible')
    });
    $('li').mouseout(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.actions').css('visibility', 'hidden')
    })
});
```

for more
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/show-hide-a-div-with-mouseover-and-mouseout-on-li/6441/2